# LINUX executar script python no terminal

Tags: python, linux

Criei um script simples em python em seguida um lançador no desktop para rodar esse script no terminal mas não esta abrindo o terminal. Quando clico para abrir o lançador nada acontece.

hello.py (script)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print('Hello World!')
```

hello.desktop (lançador)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Hello
Exec=/home/mint/pythonapp/hello.py
Comment=
Terminal=true
Icon=cinnamon-panel-launcher
Type=Application
```

Fiz o comando pra tornar executavel tambem mas não mudou nada

```
sudo chmod +x /home/mint/pythonapp/hello.py
```

Se eu rodar o comando `/home/mint/pythonapp/hello.py` direto no terminal funciona.

Linux mint 19.1

Comment: Além de colocar +x no arquivo .py, é preciso colocar +x também no arquivo desktop;
Além disso o programa não faz nada, então o terminal vai fechar muito rápido e quase nem vai dar para ver. Coloque alguma coisa demorada no seu programa para dar tempo de ver o terminal aberto

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O script está funcionando e está abrindo o terminal. O problema é que ele é bem simples e curto, portanto o terminal abre e fecha bem rápido e nem dá para ver.
Apenas Para testar você pode fazer o seguinte no script:

```
import time

print "Hello"

time.sleep(5)

print "World"
```

Isso irá pausar a execução do programa em 5 segundos, tempo suficiente para você ver se realmente funciona ou não.

Answer (score -3):

Você terá que ir no terminal e colocar:

```
DISPLAY=:0 python3 'lugar do diretório'/arquivo.py
```

um exemplo é:

```
DISPLAY=:0 python3 'Área de Trabalho'/arquivo.py
```